# Trouble inserting data in NodeJS / ReactJS app, returning a promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, redux

I am finding it impossible to get data into my store with ReactJS.
I have a Node server and its serving http://localhost:9000/products
But when fetching the data and passing it to a reducer as JSON I get the error from my reducer:

**TypeError: action.products.reduce is not a function**

It looks like it is returning a promise rather than JSON.

My fetch function looks like this:

```
export async function get () {
    return fetch('http://localhost:9000/products').then(response => response.json()).then(response => { return response })
}
export default {get}
```

The API:

```
import { get } from '../actions/get'
const TIMEOUT = 1000
console.log(get())
export default {
  getProducts: (cb, timeout) => setTimeout(() => cb(get()), timeout || TIMEOUT),
  buyProducts: (payload, cb, timeout) => setTimeout(() => cb(), timeout || TIMEOUT)
}
```

And my reducer function

```
const byId = (state = {}, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case RECEIVE_PRODUCTS:
      return {
        ...state,
        ...action.products.reduce((obj, product) => {
          obj[product.id] = product
          return obj
        }, {})
      }
    default:
      const { productId } = action
      if (productId) {
        return {
          ...state,
          [productId]: products(state[productId], action)
        }
      }
      return state
  }
}
```

I hope I have explained ok. Any help appreciated.

Comment: You are correct - `fetch` returns a promise. You'll need to read up on `fetch` (and probably also on promises) to understand why and how to get your data.

Comment: Thanks, I read up and fixed the issue. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by changing the API file to:

```
let products
fetch('http://localhost:9000/products')
  .then(
    function(response) {
      if (response.status !== 200) {
        console.log('Looks like there was a problem. Status Code: ' +
          response.status);
        return;
      }
      response.json().then(function(data) {
        products = data
      });
    }
  )
  .catch(function(err) {
    console.log('Fetch Error :-S', err);
});
export default {
  getProducts: (cb, timeout) => setTimeout(() => cb(products), timeout || TIMEOUT),
  buyProducts: (payload, cb, timeout) => setTimeout(() => cb(), timeout || TIMEOUT)
}
```